# How to compare the integer value of a text/string in OUTER JOIN ON clause in an SQL statement?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to execute the SQL statement below in VBA code written for MS Access.

I want the integer values of the ID fields to be compared in the `JOIN ON` criteria.

I get an error when using `CInt()`. I've also tried `Val()`, `CAST()`, and `Convert()`.

```
Set RecordSet = "SELECT A.id, B.id 
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON CInt(A.id)=CInt(B.id)"
```

Comment: I assume you have tried: SELECT A.id, B.id FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id. Also you know that in your select A.id and B.id will always be equal so one is redundant, unless you're using it as a check.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm actually trying to do an outer join, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: So your entire ID field contains only numbers?

Comment: I see, in that case you should consider the Nz function maybe

Comment: Yes the entire id contains only numbers. For example A.id=0123, and B.id=00123 . I want to compare the value integer of the two so that A.id=B.id is true. Can I use the Nz function in an SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your id fields are indeed integers, `CInt()` should work fine.  If your numbers are larger, try `CLng()`:

```
SELECT A.id, B.id 
FROM A 
   INNER JOIN B ON CLng(A.id)=CLng(B.id)
```

Comment: I see your edit about MS Access.  CInt() should work if all id fields are indeed integers.  If not, look at CLng()

Comment: I'm using MS Access. Yes, I've already tried using Cast(). This is the error I get: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Execute' of object '_Connection' failed.

Comment: When I use CInt() or CLng(), I get a Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Invalid use of Null

Comment: Have you tested it as a query in Access?  If so, can you execute the query from VBA that way (calling your saved query)?  Don't see anything wrong with the above example.

Comment: I tried creating the query in Access. So in the Criteria I put: CInt(A.id)=CInt(B.id) but I get a an Overflow message.

Comment: Sounds like you have numbers in your ID columns greater than those allowed for an Int -- have you tried CLng as well -- that supports higher numeric values.

Comment: I used CLng() instead, and I get the message: Invalid use of null.

Comment: Then try the Nz function -- sounds like you have null data in your Id fields.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing this right. So I create a query in MS Access. I select table A and table B. Then at the bottom of the page: the first column, first row ('Field:') I put id, the second row ('Table:') I put A. The second column, first row ('Field:') I put id, the second row ('Table:') I put B. Where do I put Nz(CLng(A.id))=Nz(CLng(B.id)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Lillyana the best would be do the `outer join` query in MS ACCESS and then go the sql view.

- [MS ACCESS outer join](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx)

Then as for `Nz` function: It will return string value (custom defined string value) when the value of your columnn is `null`

- [Nz](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx)

Usual case for the error you are getting is due to,

- [The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query that performs the first join and then include that query in your SQL statement. (Error 3258).](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080761359.aspx)

Comment: @Lillyanna can you please show us what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I went to your MS Access outer join link and followed the directions for an outer join. Then when I tried to run the query, I got this message: "The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query that performs the first join and then include that query in your SQL statement."  I'm only trying to make one outer join between A and B ON A.id=B.id

Comment: And this is the query it generates: SELECT A.id, B.id
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id;

Comment: Can you please rename one of the `id`s? e.g. A.id (so the table A make it to be AID)... Are you sure that these two are indendent two tables or rather derived queries?

Comment: A and B are two independent tables which both have the ID field. Unfortunately I cannot rename any of the fields from the two tables.